# Maximum number of pairwise linearly independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Consider vectors $v_1,\dots,v_n\in\mathbb{R}^d$. My question is: What is the maximum number of such vectors, that are **pairwise** linearly independent?

Clearly, if we remove the word **pairwise** the answer is $d$, but it feels the number is larger. Is this known explicitly?

Comment: If by pairwise linear independence you mean that one is not multiple of the other, then taking the vectors of norm $1$ is an uncountably infinite set that is pairwise linear independent

Comment: Thanks everyone. Simple, yet nice examples all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the case $d=2$. Then you have that the vectors $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$ and $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$ are pairwise linearly independent vectors, for example. Indeed, the set of all vectors of length $1$ (unit circle) consists of pairwise linearly independent vectors (except, of course, those pairs on the same line). Notice that such set is uncountable.

The same argument can be extended to any dimension $d$. Hence, the maximum number is infinity.

Answer (score 4):

For e.g. $d=2$ the collection $\{(1,r)\mid r\in\mathbb R\}$ is pairwise independent.

Observe that equality $\lambda(1,r)+\mu(1,r')=(0,0)$ leads to $\lambda=\mu=0$ if $r\neq r'$.

Answer (score 2):

In dimension $2$ the uncountable set of all vectors $(x,y)$ of length $1$ with $x > 0$ is pairwise independent.

(Added the constraint $x>0$ since the pair $\{v,-v\}$ is obviously dependent.)

Comment: Well, strictly speaking some pairs consist of a vector and its negative but that is a negligible subset of the set of pairs.

Comment: @Vincent Yes, of course. Edited.